# No OpenID endpoint found

Tags: openid, delegation

Got a problem with my openID.

A couple weeks ago I noticed I could no longer log in with my URL delegating to an underlying OpenID provider (getopenid).  I checked their server and it was returning and error, so I switched over to myopenid.com.  I'm still not able to log in anywhere though (luckily, my browser hasn't pushed me out of this login yet!).

I get openid endpoint not found.  I'm using these elements:

```
<link rel="openid.server" href="http://www.myopenid.com/server" /> 
<link rel="openid.delegate" href="http:/ /fberriman.myopenid.com/" /> 
<link rel="openid2.local_id" href="http://fberriman.myopenid.com" /> 
<link rel="openid2.provider" href="http://www.myopenid.com/server" /> 
<meta http-equiv="X-XRDS-Location" content="http://www.myopenid.com/xrds?username=fberriman.myopenid.com" />
```

(in the head of fberriman.com)

Is it a mistake in the tags (copied from myopenid's help pages, just to be on the safe side), a wordpress related problem or something on the server?  I can't get the openid test page to even return me an error other than the 'no endpoint found'.  Any pointers greatly appreciated (I'm no server admin, mind you).

Comment: some details would be good: where are you trying to use it, etc..

Comment: hmm... You reminded my I have to renew my subscription of Nature :p

Comment: Suspect this is more of a serverfault.com issue perhaps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the source on `http://fberriman.com/`, I find:

```
<link rel="openid.server"
        href="http://www.myopenid.com/server" />
  <link rel="openid.delegate"
        href="http:/ /fberriman.myopenid.com/" />
                   ^^^ There's an extra space here
```

So OpenID consumers that support OpenID version 1 might get confused.

Comment: Almost.  I should follow my own advice and validate pages before wondering why something is broken.  Deleted an element in my haste to update my new openID which was preventing it from parsing correctly.  Thanks for your help.